# can you add a webhook notification with github on public repos?

Tags: ruby, git, github

I'm using octokit for ruby to try and create webhook notifications for public repos.  I can't tell from the docs if this is possible or not, here are the docs I reference: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#create-a-hook
are webhooks only allowed to be created for projects you are a part of? I want to be notified of certain public repos on github programatically.
 I try to create a webhook with this code and get 404 :

```
github_client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token => github_access_key)
github_client.create_hook(
  'github/ghfw-build-extra',
  'web',
  {
    :url => "http://testsite.com/github_webhook_event_handler",
    :content_type => 'json',
    :insecure_url => '1'
  },
  {
    :events => ['push'],
    :active => true
  }
)
```

the error I get is:

Octokit::NotFound: POST https://api.github.com/repos/github/ghfw-build-extra/hooks: 404 - Not Found // See: https://developer.github.com/v3
from /Users/bboy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/octokit-4.2.0/lib/octokit/response/raise_error.rb:16:in `on_complete'

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a hook on a public repo, but [the code](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/719483524b930146580a997284fdd9719a5b0cdf/lib/octokit/client/hooks.rb#L44-L46) does mention:

```
  # Create a hook
  #
  # Requires authenticated client.
```

So make sure you are authenticated *before* calling that method.

Also, the same code mention as an example a config

```
  #     {
  #       :url => 'http://something.com/webhook',
  #       :content_type => 'json'
  #     },
```

In your case, maybe `testsite.com/github_webhook_event_handler` should be `http://testsite.com/github_webhook_event_handler`.

Comment: i am using an authenticated user and i do have http:// in my url, i had just changed the real url. the error I get while authenticated is that the repo doesnt exist. I updated my example to be more clear

Comment: @jas did you try with other public repos? Or with a public repo that you have created?

Answer (score 0):

At least using the github UI, you can't add webhooks for public projects if you don't have write/admin access. I assume the same will happen using the API